# How to get resume after suspend working on 15.04 lubuntu on HP mini 110-3627tu?

Tags: 15.04, lubuntu, suspend, hp, resume

Lubuntu 15.04
HP mini 110-3627tu

My netbook will not resume after suspending. 
This is regardless of the method used to suspend - close lid or via GUI.

Suspend seems to work. The screen goes blank, hard disk goes quiet, wifi light goes out and the power button flashes slowly.

When I try to resume, by pressing a key or clicking on touchpad, the screen stays black, the hard disk wakes up, the Wi-Fi light comes back on, the power button light comes on solid, but nothing is working. Pressing the Wi-Fi hot key does not turn off Wi-Fi.

Only thing to get out of this is two or three hard resets. Resetting once brings about the same state as before. Second reset, it comes on for half a second then turns off, then starts again but back to the same blank screen state.

If I hold the power button during the second reset, it will force shutdown again and next time it will restart normally.

I am totally new to Ubuntu and Linux. I have been fairly successful fixing issues in the past by searching solutions on here or other forums, but this time none of the fixes I've found so far are working.